# How to get application domain for registering metadata in AnnotationProvider

Tags: annotations, haxe, hexmachina

How can I get an annotation provider for registering a metadata via annotation provider?

I'm using a top level domain, but need a domain for application:

```
cast (AnnotationProvider.getAnnotationProvider( TopLevelDomain.DOMAIN ), AnnotationProvider).registerMetaData("URL", getSimpleUrl);
```

Comment: Could you specify your need? Each `AnnotationProvider` is attached to one domain. By default is `TopLevelDomain.DOMAIN`, but if you need to define one limited to a module, you can use the module domain to register it.